# Generate Ranking with combination of strings

Tags: javascript, combinations, ranking

I have inputs like :

```
var a = [23, 45, 21], b = [45, 23], c = [21, 32], d = [23], e= [32], f= [50, 54];
```

These all are separate entities and can be passed only one array at a time.
i.e generateRanks(a). sometimes later, generateRanks(b)

Result is stored in global variable. For each time, i make a call with input, the result is updated.

And the result should includes the ranking of all combination of values from the array.

The output should be like :

```
 {
  "21": 2,
  "23": 3,
  "32": 2,
  "45": 2,
  "52": 1,
  "54": 1,
  "23, 45": 2,
  "23, 45, 21": 1,
  "21, 32": 1,
  "50 : 54": 1,
  "50" : 1
}
```

This is what I'm tried

```
var result;
function generateRank(abc) {

 if(!result) {
   result = {};
 }

var spl = getCombinations(abc);    


spl.forEach(function(st, index) {
    var fArrayKey = st.split(":");


    var noMatch = true;

    Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log(key);
        var matchedKey = containsAllStrings(key, fArrayKey);

        if(matchedKey) {
            console.log("macthed true ");
            result[key] = result[key] + 1;
            noMatch = false;
        }
        else {
            console.log("macthed false ");
            noMatch = true;
        }
    });

    if(noMatch) {
        result[fArrayKey] = 1;
    }


});

}

function containsAllStrings(word, array) {

    for(var k=0; k<array.length; k++) {
        if(word.indexOf(array[k]) == -1) {
           return false;
        }
    }

    return true;

}

function getCombinations(chars) {
  var result = [];
  var f = function(prefix, chars) {
    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
      result.push(prefix + chars[i]);
      f(prefix + chars[i] + ":", chars.slice(i + 1));
    }
  }
  f('', chars);
  return result;
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the arrays and take all combinations and count the occurence of the combinations.

```js
function getCombinations(array) {

    function fork(i, t) {
        if (i === array.length) {
            t.length && result.push(t);
            return;
        }
        fork(i + 1, t.concat(array[i]));
        fork(i + 1, t);
    }

    var result = [];
    fork(0, []);
    return result;
}

function addCombination(array, object) {
    getCombinations(array.sort((a, b) => a - b))
        .forEach(a => object[a.join(', ')] = (object[a.join(', ')] || 0) + 1);
}

var a = [23, 45, 21],
    b = [45, 23],
    c = [21, 32],
    d = [23],
    e = [32],
    f = [50, 54],
    result = Object.create(null);

addCombination(a, result);
addCombination(b, result);
addCombination(c, result);
addCombination(d, result);
addCombination(e, result);
addCombination(f, result);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var result = {}

function reduceRanks(ranks) {
  var setId = ranks.join(',')

  if (!result[setId]) result[setId] = 0
  result[setId]++

  ranks.forEach(function(x) {
    if (!result[x]) result[x] = 0
    result[x]++
  })

  return result
}


var ranks = [
  [23, 45, 21],
  [45, 23],
  [21, 32],
  [23],
  [32],
  [50, 54]
]

ranks.forEach(function(rank) {
  reduceRanks(rank)
})
console.log(result)
// {21: 2, 23: 4, 32: 3, 45: 2, 50: 1, 54: 1, 23,45,21: 1, 45,23: 1, 21,32: 1, 50,54: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one function to get all combinations and in another function count each combination as key.

```js
var a = [23, 45, 21], b = [45, 23],c = [21, 32],d = [23],e = [32],f = [50, 54];
var arr = [a, b, c, d, e, f]

function comb(arr) {
  var result = [];

  function repeat(prev, arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(e, i) {
      var key = prev.length ? prev + ', ' + String(e) : String(e);
      result.push(key);
      repeat(key, arr.slice(i + 1))
    })
  }

  repeat('', arr);
  return result;
}

function count(data) {
  return data.reduce(function(r, e) {
    e.sort();
    comb(e).forEach(a => !r[a] ? r[a] = 1 : r[a] += 1)
    return r;
  }, {})
}

console.log(count(arr))
```